# SonarQube MSBuild in Azure DevOps Server build pipleline failed on Run Code Analysis task

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan

We have an error in our build pipeline when running the code analysis with SonarQube.

> **The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed**: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects. Possible causes:
>     1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
>     2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported
>     3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
>     4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
>
> 12:24:27.808  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
>
> D:\B2_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_xxxx\4.6.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe  failed with return code: 1

This error appears **randomly**, we couldn't identify why sometimes it's failing while most of the times it's working.

What could cause this? How can I find more information about the error?

I tried running the tool in my local machine (`SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin`, `MSBuild.exe xxxx.sln /t:Rebuild`, `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end`) but this works every times without any errors.

Regards.